# JOIN with 3 tables, and MAX value for a column combination

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rdbms, mysql-8.0

I have 3 tables with name `USER`, `SCORE` and `LEVEL` as given below.

```
USER
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
| 1 | Mr Alexander   |
| 2 | Ms. Duma       |
+----+---------------+

LEVEL
+----+------+
|id | seq   |
+----+------+
| 1 | 1     |
| 2 | 2     |
+---+-------+

SCORE
+----+---------+------------+-------+
|id | user_id  |  level_id  | score |
+----+---------+------------+-------+
| 1 | 1        |1           |3      | 
| 2 | 1        |2           |2      |   
| 3 | 1        |1           |4      |
| 4 | 1        |1           |2      | 
| 5 | 2        |1           |3      |
+---+----------+------------+-------+
```

From these tables, I'm trying to prepare a scoreboard, in which each user will be arranged based on their level, and score. And for each user, only highest level and corresponding highest score in that level will be shown.

I have written a `JOIN` query as below for this purpose.

```
SELECT user.name, MAX(level.seq) as level, MAX(score.score) as score FROM
api_score score
JOIN api_level level ON level.id = score.level_id
JOIN api_user user ON user.id = score.user_id
group by user.id, level.seq
ORDER BY level DESC, score DESC;
```

But, this query is returning all levels highest score in each level. How can I modify this query so that only highest level will returned be shown for each user?

Comment: That's because you are grouping by the `level.seq` removing it may give you the right results. As a side note this is result of BS MySQL not following SQL Ansi standards, otherwise you would receive an error about your group by

Comment: @jorge-compos, if I remove `GROUP BY` for `level.seq`, it will return all time highest score for the user, but not the highest score in highest level.

Comment: Ok, so which version of MySQL are you using? And just to be a little bit more clear can you add from your sample examples what would be the desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull out the *entire* top row per user, you cannot use aggregation only. Instead, you need some *filtering*.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select name, level, score
from (
select 
    user.name, 
    level.seq as level, 
    score.score as score,
    row_number() over(partition by user.id order by level.seq desc, score.score desc) rn
    from api_score score
    join api_level level on level.id = score.level_id
    join api_user user on user.id = score.user_id
) t
where rn = 1
order by level desc, score desc;
```